# MySql - How do you create an average based on a count?

Tags: mysql

For example I have count that will count how many concerts a musician will play in. I would then like to sum up the prices of the concerts they play in but then / by the number of concerts they play in. Is there a way to do this and put those values into a view?

Thank you!

Comment: The question's too broad. However, you can make use of MySQL's aggregate functions such as `COUNT()` and `AVG()` and `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways you could do this:
1) Using the "Average" functino in MySQL someone suggested as a comment to your OP.
Tutorial can be found here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-avg/

2) You can do the math manually by creating a user variable for the sum of prices then a user variable for count of concerts and then a third user variable that does your math. Then output that number. Here is the code you could need:

```
# Start by getting our to independent variables we will need to create our average
SET @prices := sum(( #query to find all prices of concerts
              ));
SET @concerts := count(( #query to count all of the concerts someone belongs to
                  ));

# do the math to average the numbers
SET @average := @prices / @concert;

# Now output that average to the user
SELECT @average;
```